# set Cell Style during export to excel in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid, xlsx-js

According to this link :
http://plnkr.co/edit/w8w96ltypkxrZAWA54c1?p=preview
I would set style to cell by this code :

```
s: { fill:{bgColor: {rgb: "034221" }},font:{name:"Aharoni"}}
```

but after downloading excel these styles are still not set.

Answer (score 1):

I received answerd , reason of this problem for dont adding full version of xlx-js, for avoid some this isuues adding :
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.10.5/xlsx.js
to HTML file .